# PHP function doesn't see a global variable if it's not declared global outside of the function

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, global

The code [from the official example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

Result: 2

If `$a` and `$b` are declared `global` outside the function then it works.

```
<?php
global $a, $b; // ← added this
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

Result: 3

PHP 5.6.4

Why so?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for the comments. Apparently, the problem is in the CMS. I will look for the reason in it.

Comment: Your first example doesn't result in 2, it results in 3, see: [PHP fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/ba843). I'll test it in your PHP version as well, one moment.

Comment: Same result, I get 3 not 2, see: [PHP fiddle](https://3v4l.org/OZu6H#v5.6.4). Even [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) says: _"The above script will output 3"_